# Fiddler 2 or 4 not working in windows 10

Tags: fiddler

Fiddler 2 or 4 is not working in my windows 10. I cannot capture traffic for any browser. Before upgrade to windows 10 it was working in windows 8. Some body has the sam problem? Any Solution?.

Comment: Fiddler is used daily by thousands on Windows 10. Update your question with the answers to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/httpfiddler/SsZnGxdxklg

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue whereby not HTTPS traffic could be picked up by Fiddler in Windows 10.

Resolved as follows:
In Fiddler (v4.6.2):
Tools Menu >> Fiddler Options >> HTTPS Tab >> Actions button >> Reset All Certificates.

Apparently the issue (at least the one I was having) was caused by having a mixture of old and new certs:

> I’ve made changes to the latest versions of Fiddler to improve the
>   performance of certificate creation, and to avoid problems with new
>   certificate validation logic coming to Chrome and Firefox. The biggest
>   of the Fiddler changes is that CertEnroll is now the default
>   certificate generator on Windows 7 and later. 
>   Unfortunately, this
>   change can cause problems for users who have previously trusted the
>   Fiddler root certificate; the browser may show an error message like
>   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID or The certificate was not issued by a
>   trusted certificate authority.

Ref:
https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/

Answer (score 2):

Check if your browser proxy is set to localhost:8888 when fiddler is running.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot that you have opened the Filters functional,then there are no data captured.